# How can i disable an drop down menu item after selection?

Tags: javascript, html

Category is the first item yo will see i want it to be removed or disabled after is is selected so that it doesn't show when viewing the other drop down menu items.

```
<select NAME="category" style="width:130px; background-color:#FFF; font-weight:bold; font-size:12px;" ONCHANGE="setup(document.search1.category.value)"> 
  <option value="category" selected="selected">Category</option> 
  <option value="cleaning">Cleaning</option> 
  <option value="cooling">Cooling</option>
  <option value="heating">Heating</option> 
  <option value="kitchen">Kicthen</option> 
  <option value="lighting">Lighting</option> 
  <option value="washroom">Washroom</option> 
</select>
```

Comment: see my comment. Just tested it in jsfiddle

Answer (score 1):

This will remove the slected Item

```
<select NAME="category" style="width:130px; background-color:#FFF; font-weight:bold; font-size:12px;" onchange="this.remove(this.selectedIndex);"> 
  <option value="category" selected="selected">Category</option> 
  <option value="cleaning">Cleaning</option> 
  <option value="cooling">Cooling</option>
  <option value="heating">Heating</option> 
  <option value="kitchen">Kicthen</option> 
  <option value="lighting">Lighting</option> 
  <option value="washroom">Washroom</option> 
</select>​
```

Comment: Could be i will try it and see if it works how i require it to

Comment: <option value="category" selected="selected" onchange="this.disabled='true'">Category</option> will that work?

Comment: The question is somewhat unclear, but I think what he is asking for is to have the very first option disabled or removed once something else is selected.  This first entry is basically a label of the select box.  In this case "Category".

Comment: no, because the onchange is for the SELECT, not for the OPTION

Comment: basically what i want is to disable or remove the "CATEGORY" label after it is selected and just show the other dropdown options

Comment: @DamzWildFirePrince my code should do that, I edited it, does it not work now?

Comment: @DamzWildFirePrince it does: see this http://jsfiddle.net/PNYfZ/1/
Just took out the function and made it inline.. this will disable any selection you make, did u not want this? Or u wanted it to work for ONLY category? If so do a check to see if the selectedIndex==0 and disable if true..

Comment: @SajjanSarkar it disables the entire category just want the word "CATEGORY" not showing after it is selected after category is selected on thing tht shud show is  <option value="cooling">Cooling</option>
  <option value="heating">Heating</option> 
  <option value="kitchen">Kicthen</option> 
  <option value="lighting">Lighting</option> 
  <option value="washroom">Washroom</option>

Comment: Then why did u say u wanted to DISABLE the item, your question is not clear at all.

Comment: @SajjanSarkar guess i didn't phrase the question properly.  i apologize for that

Comment: @DamzWildFirePrince have updated the code to remove whatever you select, will this at least work?

Comment: @DamzWildFirePrince if it worked for u please take the time and accept it as an answer,it at least recognizes the time we spent on it

Comment: @SajjanSarkar cannot remove this code "ONCHANGE="setup(document.search1.category.value)" " because that is linked to the other menu items in the drop down menu

Comment: @DamzWildFirePrince Ok, so leave it there.. Did the code work with respect to the problem u posted above?

Answer (score 0):

You should use it like this `disabled = 'disabled'`

```
<select NAME="category" style="width:130px; background-color:#FFF; font-weight:bold; font-size:12px;" onchange="javascript:this.disabled = 'disabled';"> 
  <option value="category" selected="selected">Category</option> 
  <option value="cleaning">Cleaning</option> 
  <option value="cooling">Cooling</option>
  <option value="heating">Heating</option> 
  <option value="kitchen">Kicthen</option> 
  <option value="lighting">Lighting</option> 
  <option value="washroom">Washroom</option> 
</select>​
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to remove the "category" line item after a user selects a different item from your drop down, you would do this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {

    $('#selectList').change(function () {
        if (this[0].value == "category")
        {
            this.remove(this[0]);
        }
    });

});
</script>

<select id='selectList' name="category" 
style="width:130px; background-color:#FFF; font-weight:bold; font-size:12px;"> 
    <option value="category">Category</option> 
    <option value="cleaning">Cleaning</option> 
    <option value="cooling">Cooling</option>
    <option value="heating">Heating</option> 
    <option value="kitchen">Kicthen</option> 
    <option value="lighting">Lighting</option> 
    <option value="washroom">Washroom</option> 
</select>
```

That will remove the Category row from the drop down and ONLY the category row.